# Exclude specify index from Parameter type of function

Tags: typescript, parameters

```
function fun1(a:number, b:string, c:()=>void)
{

}


function fun2(...args:Parameters<typeof fun1>)
{

}
```

I want exclude a specific index of `fun1`'s parameters from function `fun2`'s parameter types.

Basically the result should be:

```
function fun2(b:string, c:()=>void)
{

}
```

I tried using `Omit<Parameters<typeof this._call>, "0">` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using `Omit` is that it returns an object type rather than a tuple type (technically because `Omit<T, U>` is not a homomorphic mapping on `T`).

```
type Test = Omit<[0, 1], 0>
// type Test = {[x: number]: 0 | 1; [Symbol.iterator]: () => IterableIterator<0 | 1>; ...
```

To preserve the tuple type, you can declare a conditional type `Tail` that uses `infer` to obtain the the tail of `T` (kind of like pattern matching on the tuple structure):

```
type Tail<T extends readonly unknown[]> =
  T extends readonly [unknown, ...infer Rest] ? Rest : never
```

(The `readonly`'s are required to also allow `Tail` to be used on read-only tuples.) You can use `Tail` like this:

```
function fun2(...args: Tail<Parameters<typeof fun1>>) {}
// function fun2(b: string, c: () => void): void
```

[TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/mL2Rkw)

Comment: Perfect! Can you explain it a little?